Blender model is glithing after Bakery light bake in Unity
Not really a Blender question but I don't know where to go with this anymore.
I have made some Blender models, everything looks fine in Blender, everything looks fine in Unity too, up until lights are baked in Unity. Afterwards one of the meshes starts glitching like on this picture:

This is what it looks like in Blender (and in Unity too, before baking):

Other meshes in the scene seemed to be baked fine.
What could be the cause of this?

I'd recommend contacting the maker himself, @guycalledfrank on twitter. Since this only happens with Bakery.

Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately he isn't responding, not really sure if he is active on twitter anymore.

He is...or at least, his last post is 3 days ago and last reply was yesterday. Might be he has too many dms to notice.
